# Application Insights: why is data still temporarily inaccessible?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azureportal

(There doesn't seem to be an option to select Application Insights when reporting a support issue in the Azure portal, hence this post)

For about 12 hours I keep seeing the following error message in the Azure portal when I try and look at Application Insights for a particular App Service:

> Data is temporarily inaccessible, see http://aka.ms/aistatus .

That link currently says:

> All Application Insights Services are now working as expected.

which is clearly incorrect!

Anyone from the Azure team know what is going on here please? (And why isn't Application Insights available as an option in the drop down list when submitting a support request please?).

Answer (score 53):

For anyone coming across this issue, try disabling your ad-blocker and see if that fixes it.

In my case, Live Metrics would show this error because my ad-blocker was blocking the request.

---

<s>If anyone from Microsoft/Azure sees this, the "aka.ms" link in the error message just goes to an empty Bing page now. Not sure if it worked previously.</s>
EDIT: Seems to be fixed now.

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you for helping me with this issue.

Comment: I can't believe that worked. Looks like Ublock Origin blocks the domain monitor.azure.com, and the live metrics page makes calls to livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com. It's probably possible to add an exception in Ublock Origin for this, but the UI is an absolute horror to work with, so it's just simpler to push the off-button for the entire site.

Comment: Same here. uBlock Origin was blocking the mandatory requests.

Comment: I just added portal.azure.com as a trusted site in uBlock Origin and it's working again.

Answer (score 3):

Application Insights should appear in the drop down. Please see picture :)
Application Insights Support Request:

[image]