# Azure Portal in application insights while opening Live metrics gives us error Data is temporarily inaccessible

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights, metrics, live

Azure Portal in application insights while opening  Live metrics gives us error Data is temporarily inaccessible. The updates on our status are posted here https://aka.ms/aistatus

[image]

Created a new application insight via Azure Portal still facing same issue

Comment: Why do you think creating a new instance will solve anything? If there is an outage or a firewall issue this will solve nothing.

Comment: Please refer similar issue  @[SOThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36532350/application-insights-why-is-data-still-temporarily-inaccessible)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Application Insights: why is data still temporarily inaccessible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36532350/application-insights-why-is-data-still-temporarily-inaccessible)

Answer (score 1):

I do agree with @Peter Bons that this issue occurs mostly when there is an outage or a firewall issue.

As per @rgrace-puck 's [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36532350/application-insights-why-is-data-still-temporarily-inaccessible),

> Try, disabling add blocker

I have faced similar issue and the above solution of disabling add blocker solved my issue.